# How to grab a user's Avatar from Tumblr

Tags: objective-c, ios7, tumblr

I am working on Login with Tumblr in my application.

Everything is working fine, I am able to get blog name, access key and access secret key.
But not able to get the avatar of the profile.

I am using *GTMOAuth*.

Please suggest me how I can get the profile pic.

Comment: To help fix your code, we have to see some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, the correct way to get a profile is avatar is to invoke

```
/avatar
```

In particular, you can get a blog's avatar in 9 different sizes. The default size is 64x64.

```
/avatar/512
```

would grab the URL of an avatar of 512x512

Reference: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-avatar.

You can use the URL to download/display the specific image.

But do you need something in particular?

**Note** There is also an SDK for Objective-C available on GitHub [TMTumblrSDK](https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK).

Comment: Thanks,Exactly same i was looking for.